# Converting Series to Quarterly Data

Tags: python-3.x, series

I have data that currently looks like this:

```
Index Year Quarter
0     2015   1
1     2015   1
2     2015   2
3     2015   3
4     2015   3
5     2015   3
6     2015   4
.      .     . 
.      .     .
.      .     .  
8010  2016   1
8011  2016   2
8012  2016   2
8013  2016   3
8014  2016   4
```

Is there any way that I can make it look like columns Time1, Time2, or Time3 below? Any of the three Time-columns will do. Many thanks in advance.

```
Index  Time1   Time2    Time3
0     2015-Q1  2015Q1  2015:Q1
1     2015-Q1  2015Q1  2015:Q1
2     2015-Q2  2015Q2  2015:Q2
3     2015-Q3  2015Q3  2015:Q3
4     2015-Q3  2015Q3  2015:Q3
5     2015-Q3  2015Q3  2015:Q3
6     2015-Q4  2015Q4  2015:Q4
.      .    .    .        .
.      .    .    .        .
.      .    .    .        .
8010  2016-Q1  2016Q1  2016:Q1
8011  2016-Q2  2016Q2  2016:Q2
8012  2016-Q2  2016Q2  2016:Q2
8013  2016-Q3  2016Q3  2016:Q3
8014  2016-Q4  2016Q4  2016:Q4
```

Comment: Is what you show as input the content of a text file? Did you try something? What specific problem did you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016],
                   'Quarter':[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]})

df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str)
df['Quarter'] = df['Quarter'].astype(str)

df['Time1'] = df['Year'] + '-Q' + df['Quarter']
df['Time2'] = df['Year'] + 'Q' + df['Quarter']
df['Time3'] = df['Year'] + ':Q' + df['Quarter']
```